# How do I calculate the total arbitrage of two data sets in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trading

I have a list of volumes and prices of 'apples' that were sold by a wholesaler over time, and a separate list of volumes and prices of apples that were bought by consumers over time.

I need to calculate the 'arbitrage' opportunity in this market i.e. if I could store apples indefinitely, how many could I have bought from the wholesaler and sold for a higher price to a consumer. Chronology does not matter, however I do need to prioritise in order of arbitrage opportunity (i.e. potential profit made).

I have:
Wholesale sells

```
ID    vol     price
1    200      5
2    400      4
3    600      3
4    100      3
5    30       2
6    620      1
```

Consumer buys

```
id    vol     price
a     100      4
b     150      2
c     60       2
d     700      2
e     20       2
f     600      1
```

I want:

```
ID  vol  price No. arbitraged
1   200   5     0
2   400   4     0
3   600   3     0
4   100   3     0
5   30    2     0
6   620   1     620

id  vol  price No. arbitraged
a   100   4     100
b   150   2     150
c   60    2     60
d   700   2     310
e   20    2     0
f   600   1     0
```

In other words, I bought the 620 apples for £1 from the wholesaler and sold 100 of them for £4 and 520 of them for £2 across a total of 4 consumers (a,b,c and d - although consumer d only bought a proportion of her total apples from me).

NB - I can sell 'apples' to the consumer in advance of buying them from the wholesaler hence the requirement to see the outcome in both formats.

Comment: This comes across like a homework question, just well formatted to be a Stack Overflow Question. What have *you* tried so far to achieve the result set you want and why didn't it work? Or what research have you performed to try and resolve the issue and what about that research didn't you understand?

Comment: Hi Larnu, apologies if it sounds like homework - I am actually trying to start my own business after recently been made redundant and decided to simplify the problem as much as possible after reading the guidance page on how to post questions on this site. I have spent two days thinking about how to solve it but made no concrete progress and so asked the question here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Simplification is not a bad thing, but how do you go from the data under "wholesale sells" to the first part of "I want"? The data contains no information when you start buying from the wholesale. In other words, how is the `No. arbitraged` column of the wholesale orders calculated?

Comment: Thanks @Sander. The [No. arbitraged] column is calculated by working out how many apples were sold by the wholesaler at a lower price than apples bought by the consumer - the calc needs to be prioritised in order of profit. So in this example I take the lowest value apples from the wholesaler and 'assign' them to the highest value apples of the consumer. As the highest paying consumer only bought 100 apples, I can only aritrage 100 apples against her. However the second highest paying consumer still paid more than the lowest wholesale price, so I can arb another 150 apples there, and so on

Comment: ...the calculation ends when I reach the point that the next cheapest apple available from the wholesaler is the same price as the next most expensive apple bought by a consumer. Chronology doesn't matter i.e. we can assume that I could have bought all of the wholesale apples some time before any consumers started buying apples. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not an easy question because there are _many_ special cases. Covering them all  might require a full blown application or a _very_ lengthy SQL script. A few examples: your remaining stock of apples consists of 50x$1 + 100x$2. [Example 1] A customer wants to buy 75x$3 --> do you sell (50x$1 + 25x$2) or (75x$2)? [Example 2] A customer wants to buy 200x$3 --> do you sell 150 (if so, at which price(s)?) or do you sell nothing? These might be easy decisions for a sales person, but translating all this to a full script / program is a very broad question for StackOverflow. Maybe _too_ broad?

Comment: Divide this problem up in smaller chunks. You said you worked on it yourself for 2 days. Show us your attempt and indicate why it is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks Sander - in your Example 1, you sell (50x1$ and 25x$2) because that is how you maximise the profit. In Example 2, you sell 150 apples (as thats all you have) and all 150 are bought for less than $3 (although if you break it down, you sell the 50x$1 apples first, then the 100x$2 apples, as you sell in order of profit). I will try and chunk the problem up as you say - I don't have any working solution at all so far as I think it may require some kind of window function and I'm quite new to SQL. Thanks